# Vim locks up completely when pressing `ctrl+w` while using tmux + vim

Tags: neovim, tmux

I have a tmux + vim setup in which I use split panes. Every time I press `ctrl+w` to move between the vim panes, my vim instance becomes completely unresponsive. At first I thought this was a tmux issue so I disabled all my tmux plugins and shortcuts.

After disabling, I still run into this issue.

Every time I press `ctrl+w`, the whole terminal window becomes unresponsive (in my case it's iTerm2 on mac). I can switch over to other apps like my browser and everything is a bit slowed down on my computer (a simple google search hangs). And then about a minute later, things are back to normal. I can continue using vim and other apps on my computer no problem until I accidentally or intentionally tap `ctrl+w` again.

I should note that I am using neovim instead of vim.

Comment: What is your tmux prefix? Does this happen outside of tmux? With `vim --clean`? Is your `$TERM` configured correctly inside tmux? Outside? It *sounds* like something is hogging your cpu when vim freezes, but I’m guessing.

Comment: Yikes. Are you sure that the only way to recreate this is through Vim? If you could reproduce it elsewhere you could probably then move this question to an SE site with more traffic, increasing your chances of finding a solution.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm using `ctrl-j` as my prefix. I looked at the activity log and it doesn't seem to spike my CPU, iTerm2 just becomes unresponsive which baffles me even more.

Comment: @BLayer I've tried it with anything else, nano/emacs, just using the command line for other things and it seemed to not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround this.

Things I tried:

- Disabled all plugins for vim, this seemed to help for a bit but after a few presses of `ctrl+w` it went back to freezing up my iTerm2
- Used vim outside of tmux, issue still occurred.
- Disabled the `ctrl+w` keymap in iTerm2, this was unfeasible as I need to move between panes in vim.

My current workaround is to disable `ctrl+h` which would freeze up my iTerm as well and being human, I would often press `ctrl+w ctrl+h` instead of `ctrl+w, then h` and this has helped a lot.
Disabling some unused plugins helped but only for the first few instances of `ctrl+w`. At this point, I'm going to avoid using panes in vim.

Comment: As far as workarounds go, most `ctrl-w` Normal mode commands have a command-line mode alias. See `:h :wincmd`. If the problem is actually caused by `ctrl-w` itself you could at least create mappings for the commands you need (e.g. let's say you're okay with using `ctrl-x` instead of `ctrl-w` ...  `:nnoremap <c-x>w :wincmd w<cr>`) thus maintaining access to the same functionality without too much inconvenience.

Comment: BTW, the above assumes that "pressing" `ctrl-w` through a mapping like `:nnoremap <c-x>w <c-w>w` still causes problems...but does it? Because if not then that makes for even simpler mappings. (And if it does still cause problems that's an interesting data point.)